# getElementByClassName onclick issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onclick

I would like to know how can I detect that the button is clicked using  `getElementByClassName`. The button doesn't have an ID and is generated as a part of embedded iframe.

```html
<button class="playButton medium" role="application" title="Play" style="color: rgb(204)</button>
```

I am trying this script that would `alert` if the button is clicked, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
var x = document.getElementByClassName("playButton medium");
for (var i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].onclick = function() {
    alert("clicked");
  }
};
```

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly it's `getElementsByClassName()`, note the plural `s`. Secondly, you can only supply a single class as an argument to that function. Also it's better practice to use `addEventListener()` over `on*` event properties. Try this:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("playButton");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("clicked");
  });
};
```

```html
<button class="playButton medium" role="application" title="Play" style="color: rgb(204)">Play</button>
```

If you wanted to select the elements using both classes you could instead use `document.querySelectorAll('.playButton.medium')`.